# How To Find The Command Is Internal Or External In Ubuntu

Tags: command-line

Those Command Are Present In 'help' Command They Are Internal Command Or Not....

Answer (score 1):

At the very top of the `help` output:

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.18(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
These shell commands are defined internally.  Type `help' to see this list.
```

Thus, they are internal.

Answer (score 0):

If you see all the internal command in ubuntu then type 'help' command in terminal

Or

Use 'type' command to check ..

eg. $ type type

```
$ type is a shell builtin
```

Comment: Of interest: `type echo` and `which echo`. Follow this by `type -a echo`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I was just going to say that's a good answer I'd upvote, then I saw your answer on the duplicate Q so I did